# There should be at least 2 link events to make a connection

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, bpmn

I'm currently exploring how to use `Link` intermediate throw event in jBPM 6.2. From this documentation on `Link` in BPM (http://camunda.org/bpmn/reference/), it seems that we can create two link nodes and have them connected to each other.

I tried to do the same thing in jBPM diagram editor in Eclipse, however, I'm getting this error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There should be at least 2 link events to make a connection`

[image]

Additionally, it seems that we need to specify target in the link event definition details. How can we specify that in jBPM diagram editor in Eclipse?

**Edit:**

The diagram might be incorrect in that I have two `throw` links. It should be one `throw` link and one `catch` link.

**Edit:**
I've updated the diagram with one `throw` link and one `catch` link.

Comment: Difficult to tell, but shouldn't the "catching" Link event have a white arrow, according to the specification? Not sure whether Camunda does it that way, but maybe both are configured as "throwing"?

Comment: what kind of behaviour are you trying to model by using the Link element?

Comment: @salaboy I'm trying to use the `Link` element to to allow a sequence flow to connect two nodes without explicitly connecting them. (Similar to a 'worm-hole'). I would like to achieve clarity in the diagram, so that I don't have to display a very long sequence flow from one end of the graph to the other end. Is that possible to do so with the `Link` element?

Comment: @salaboy I looked through the ProcessHandler.java line 222 (https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-bpmn2/src/main/java/org/jbpm/bpmn2/xml/ProcessHandler.java) and I don't understand why it's required to have the size of `linksWithSharedNames` to be >= 2 in order to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I have to match the `Link` names of both `Throw` and `Catch` nodes. After adjusting the names, the jBPM was able to complete the workflow.

Comment: thank you so much for posting that! just to clarify, this link event can be edited under throw/catch properties, `event` tab, `edit` -> `name`